# Apple Magic Trackpad multitouch configuration

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, trackpad, magic-trackpad

Today I installed the Ubuntu 10.10 release on my Desktop PC. I was running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS with an Apple Magic Trackpad and everything was working fine. After today's *fresh* installation of Ubuntu 10.10, I don't see my Apple Magic Trackpad's multitouch working. Two-finger scrolling and three-finger third mouse button clicking are completely broken.

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue? Has anyone had success with Ubuntu 10.10 and an Apple Magic TrackPad?

Please help me to fix this issue. Your help is highly appreciated...

Comment: Note: If you have a MacBook, don't look here. This is about the Magic Trackpad only. Different drivers are needed: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9460/is-it-possible-to-get-dragging-working-on-a-macbook-multi-touch-touch-pad or http://askubuntu.com/questions/24235/macbook-pro-compatibility-multitouch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I've only had success in 10.10 by using the "synaptics" driver.

Put the following in your xorg.conf:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "multitouch touchpad"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "synaptics"
EndSection
```

Once that's done, you should be able to tweak the cursor speed, scrolling speed and other parameters with gpointing-device-settings. Not sure if it's legacy now, but you may need

```
Option "SHMConfig" "True"
```

in the above section for that as well.

Comment: Thanks alot. It worked. However, I was having one finger touch for left click and two finger touch for right click and 3 finger touch for middle click. Now, 3 finger click as expected... Single finger touch changed to right click and two finger touch changed to left click. How can change this ?. Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce that behavior. You may want to ask for assistance in the #ubuntu-touch channel on Freenode.

Comment: Thanks. Is your trackpad single touch mapped to left click ?. (for right hand mouse). I didn't had Option SHMConfig "True". Is that makes any difference ?. http://ubuntu-snippets.blogspot.com/2009/03/multi-touch-for-anyall-synaptics.html

Comment: Yes, it's left click; try adding that option.

Comment: yesterday, i added option SHMConfig "true" to my xorg.conf and i didnt reboot since i was working some important stuff.. till today afternoon 2 finger was left click... just now, i came back to work after a small break, i saw 2 finger is right click and one finger touch is left click. :).. not sure what happened and what module config related or whatever..now I'm happy with current settings....

Comment: Does the middle click work, with three fingers? I've updated the answer to make MatchDevicePath "catch-all"; it should prevent falling back to the evdev driver if the event your MT is on changes.

Comment: Is this still the most correct answer for the Magic Trackpad with version 12.04 LTS? I just got the Wireless keyboard and TrackPad today and I can say that I don't need to do some of the steps you guys did for 10.10. There is still the problem where Two Finger scroll is not active by default.

Answer (score 2):

With multiple monitors and ATI eyefinity (3 screens 5760x1080 px) I had a problem with the vertical and horizontal movement speed and acceleration of the mouse pointer with the Apple Magic trackpad in Ubuntu 11.04. (I use the ATI propriety FGLRX drivers)

Also i wanted to simulate the fast flick-to-scroll behavior with two fingers as in OSX.

My settings for the Magic trackpad in **/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "InputClass"      
    Identifier      "Apple Magic Trackpad"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
    MatchUSBID      "05ac:030e"
    Driver          "synaptics"
    Option          "VertScrollDelta"  "50"
    Option          "HorizScrollDelta" "50"
    Option          "MinSpeed"         "0.6"
    Option          "MaxSpeed"         "1.3" 
    Option          "AccelFactor"      "0.08"
    # these two options are for multiple monitors 3:1 ratio.  
    Option          "VertResolution"   "1"
    Option          "HorizResolution"  "3"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

[wiki.ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad) page about 10.10 and Apple Magic Trackpad

Answer (score 0):

Read post on omgubuntu.co.uk blog: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/benjamin-gets-his-hands-on-the-apple-magic-trackpad/