# Multitouch in PyMT-Demo under Maverick with Magic Trackpad

Tags: 10.10, multi-touch, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I have a Magic Trackpad, it's configured as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5907/apple-trackpad-multitouch-configuration/5987#5987). 
The following works:

- 1 finger Tap = Leftclick
- 2 finger Tap = Rightclick
- 3 finger Tap = Middleclick
- 2 finger Drag = Scrolling

But out of curiosity, I'd like to play with [PyMT](http://www.pymt.eu/), which comes with a nice multitouch demo (Details: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/PyMT).

When starting it with "sudo python -m pymt.tools.demo", the PyMT-Window opens but doesn't register/display any multitouching. Actually, it doesn't display anything but a blank window where the touches show show up. I was expecting something like in this [Screenshot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/PyMT?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=Screenshot-1.png).

Any ideas where I went wrong or what I didn't correctly understand? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've configured your MT to use the *synaptics* driver, it's working in a kind of "touchpad emulation" mode. My understanding is that the true multitouch and gesture functionality requires the *evdev* driver, which unfortunately doesn't provide the same basic pointing functions (two-finger scrolling, two and three-finger taps) with the MT at the moment. So for this release, true multitouch gestures and basic pointing functions are mutually exclusive, and we're resorting to *synaptics* as a temporary measure until *evdev* catches up.

You can follow multitouch-related happenings by joining the [multi-touch-dev mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~multi-touch-dev), or visiting the #ubuntu-touch channel on Freenode.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. I didn't realise that you need the evdev-driver for true multitouch :-)

Answer (score 3):

Please see this to get help and see other resources about MultiTouch in Ubuntu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch#Community%20Help

There is a detailed guide there for using the Apple MT in Ubuntu, including the PyMT demo wiki - which I have since updated.

Comment: Thanks, but I've read quite a lot of stuff in the Ubuntu Wiki before asking my question. I don't think I've come acros a section that said that the MultiTouch-Demos won't work if you use the synaptics-driver. Maybe this could be added to the "Synaptics style functionality" section here? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad

Comment: For the information of MacBook( Pro) users, this doesn't apply to MacBook( Pro)s.  The synaptics driver (included in -desktop) implements two-finger right-clicks and can be configured for scroll.  The non-configurable but quite usable multitouch X input driver from the mactel PPA gains thumb-resting and -dragging and will soon (once released) support back-swiping as well.