# MacBook Pro Compatibility, Multitouch

Tags: 10.10, hardware, multi-touch, macbook, macosx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to get dragging working on a Macbook multi-touch touch pad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9460/is-it-possible-to-get-dragging-working-on-a-macbook-multi-touch-touch-pad)

How is the hardware compatibility for the 2010 macbook pros?

Does the trackpad multitouch gesture work with 10.10? is it oversensitive?

And for anyone that has a relatively new macbook pro that is running Ubuntu, How is the general experience coming from an OSX environment?