# Magic Mouse Multitouch in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apple, magic-mouse

I'm trying to set up Ubuntu as my daily driver on my 27 inch iMac. Would the solution for the [magic trackpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5907/apple-magic-trackpad-multitouch-configuration/5987#5987) work with the magic mouse as well? This is a work computer, so I don't want to spend too much time tumbling down rabbit holes.

Answer (score 1):

The Magic Mouse works out of the box in 12.04, with right-click, middle-click, left-click, vertical scroll and horizontal scroll. As far as I can tell, more advanced functions (two-finger swipe, three-finger swipe, pinch, and zoom) don't work yet.

Comment: Just to complete Jon's answer, here is where Multitouch support's progress can be tracked: [https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch](https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch)

Answer (score 1):

I am using one right now. I just connected it via USB bluetooth dongley thingy. (technical term) The only issue right now is that I cannot invert scrolling and scrolling is not that smooth. I am still trying to figure that out. It does work though.